# True or false?: $\exists x\in\Bbb{R}\;\forall y\in\Bbb{R}(x^2>y^2\to x>y)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Determine whether $$\exists x\in\Bbb{R}\;\forall y\in\Bbb{R}(x^2>y^2\to x>y)$$ is true or false.

---

My attempt:

**First answer?**

Is true. Pick $x=1\in\Bbb{R}$. Then for all $y\in\Bbb{R}$, we have that $1^2=1>y^2$. This implies $|y|<1$, so $-1<y<1$, so $y>-1$ and $y<1$. By reduction we have $y<1$, and we are done.

**Second answer?**

We will prove that this holds for any $x,y$. From $x^2>y^2$ we have $|x|>|y|$. That is, $|y|<x$. Then, $-x<y<x$, so $y>-x$ and $y<x$. Again by simplification, we end up with $y<x$, which is the same as $x>y$.

**Questions**

1. Are both answers a correct way to solve the problem?
2. In the first answer, could I pick any value of $x$? Can I pick $x=0$? In that case I should have $0>y^2$, which is false, so the statement is true.
3. In the second answer did we prove this statement: $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}\;\forall y\in\Bbb{R}(x^2>y^2\to x>y)$?

Comment: There is an error in your second solution. Take $x=-5$ as an example.

Comment: I‘d say your first answer is correct but your second one misses an important point: consider $x=-2$ and $y=1$ Then $x^2=4 > 1 = y^2$ but $x < y$

Comment: @MartinR thanks Martin! You are right. So the correct way is the first attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer is surely correct, and you could stop here. You have shown that
$$
\exists x\in\Bbb{R}:\,\forall y\in\Bbb{R}: \, (x^2>y^2\implies x>y)
$$
because $x=1$ has the desired property.

In your second answer you claim that instead of $x=1$ one could choose an *arbitrary* $x \in \Bbb R$, but there is an error: The last implication in
$$
 x^2 > y^2 \implies |x| > |y|  \implies |y| < x
$$
is wrong for negative numbers $x$, as can be seen by choosing $y=0$. We have
$$
 x^2 > y^2 \iff |x| > |y|  \iff -|x| < y < |x|
$$
and this implies $y < x$ for *non-negative* $x$. So a correct statement would be
$$
\forall x\in\Bbb{R}_{\ge 0}:\,\forall y\in\Bbb{R}: \, (x^2>y^2\implies x>y) \, .
$$
This includes the value $x=0$: As you already noticed, $0 > y^2$ is never true, to that the implication $0 > y^2 \implies 0 > y$ holds (a “vacuous truth”).

Comment: I have a question: When I say "Then for all $y\in\Bbb{R}$, we have that $1^2=1>y^2$", this is due the hypothesis of the implication? Thanks!!

Comment: @manooooh: Sorry, but your question is unclear to me. Note that your first solution is a special case of the second solution (with $x=1$).

Comment: I mean in my first attempt, when I say "Then for all $y\in\Bbb{R}$...". This quotation is true because we have $x^2>y^2$, and since $x=1$ then $1>y^2$?

Comment: @manooooh: If you want to show that $x=1$ has the desired property then you have to show that for all $y \in \Bbb R$ the implication $1^2 > y^2 \implies y < 1$ holds. And that is true because $1^2 > y^2 \iff 1 > |y| \iff -1 < y < 1 \implies y < 1$.